# WCF Service Interface - XElement vs. XmlElement vs. xml string

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest, soap

I am doing some work which requires a WCF Service interface (in C#). The data exchanged (sent and recieved) will be in the xml format --- I cannot use strong datatypes because the interface needs to support multiple clients which have different requirements.

My question is which one of these is preferable:

```
XElement MyServiceMethod(XElement inputParam 1)
{

    XElement retValue;

    //
    // Operation occurs here
    //

    return (retValue);

}
```

**vs**

XmlElement MyServiceMethod(XmlElement inputParam 1)
{

```
XmlElement retValue;

//
// Operation occurs here
//

return (retValue);
```

}

**vs**

```
//
//inputParam is an xml formatted string
//
string MyServiceMethod(string inputParam 1)
{

    string retValue;

    //
    // Operation occurs here
    //

        //retValue is an xml formatted string
    return (retValue);

}
```

The code will be consumed via SOAP interface primarily, though it may ultimately be consumed via REST as well.

Is there a "best" approach"? Likewise, is there one that is completely not desirous.

Comment: I don't think REST will handle XmlElement or XElement very well.

Comment: Since `XElement` and `XmlElement` are C# types, if you want maximum interoperability and simple types, just use `string`.  The string can be XML.  Internally in the service you can use `XDocument.Parse` to load the string XML into an XDocument for parsing.

Comment: I use both XmlElement (straight XML) and XElement (XML Linq) depending on the situation.  If you are going to perform a lot of queries, I would use Linq.